# Design of backend TCP/IP communication with Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, backend

I have a theoretical problem i cannot find solution that easily and would love some feedback on my thought process now.

I took over this backend project after colleague, so i inherited some of his thought processes and designs, i never really designed something like this on my own, here is a problem:

I am programming backend in python between a measuring unit(MU) running on LabView, which provides me byte data over tcp/ip socket -> i parse it, cache it, store it in db, whatever, and then send it to frontend. Thing is that it is now set up as me being the server listening for connections and data transfers from MU, but data needs to flow both ways, he needs to listen too for my requests of his data. For some reason it is now programmed so that there is new connection created and closed on my server socket.

The following code is oversimplified, but i hope u get the logic.

```
self.sock = sock.socket(...) #my listening socket
self.sock.bind(self.host, self.port)
self.sock.listen(1)
client_sock, client_address = self.socket.accept()
data = client_sock.recv(100)
client_sock.close()
client_sock, client_address = self.socket.accept()
```

and so it goes on and on 4ever, I have a new thread starting for each accept(), so there can be more connections made on this socket.

Thing is as I have found out, there is not a good way to initialize connection from me to MU when i want to send data, since connections is already closed and here is where i need your help. Colleague told me that there is good reason for it to be this way since the connections are atomic and if something goes wrong, the bytestream wont be so corrupt for next data transfer, since it is whole new connection. But I find it hard to accept, my instincts say that I should rather keep the connection open, the traffic there is very frequent.

IS IT SAFE?
By this logic i see no other option than for him to have listening socket as well. How can i connect to him otherwise? no way right?

But if i could just accept this one connection and use this one for two-way traffic, is it ok? Or should both of us be server AND client? The MU should not be doing any backend stuff, we try to keep it very simple in its purpose.

I would probably go with one connection instinctively, but this colleague of mine who handed it over to me confused me with this one connection per transfer idea.

if u managed to read this far, thank you and your thoughts or experiences are welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: you have to check the documentation for labview. In general i don't see the point of establishing a connection every time. if something goes wrong and tcp will notice it (it is very unlikely that this won't happen) the connection will get closed. if nothing goes wrong, you skip the handshake and termination time. however, if it is possible that something does go wrong, you will have to have a mechanism to re-establish the connection/wait for the ME to connect and you might need a socket anyways. TCP should handle the case where both sides try to connect simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to keep a connection for two-way communication.

What exactly could happen to bytestream, so it will become "corrupted" ? Data is transferred in chunks, and if one chunk becomes invalid, you will lost it anyway.
The problem here might be that the next chunks could not be distinguished, but it's easy to defend from such cases. For example, you can use frame/message headers. After all, you can always kill connection on server side if something goes wrong (forcing other side to establish a new one).

It's also worth to mention, that if your MU was a real sensor placed in the field it would become complicated to connect to it since it's address (IP) changes dynamically.